# get asana project id

Tags: asana

I am trying to find out how to get the workspace and project id's from the main web app. I cant seem to find them anywhere.

I am attempting to write a VB.Net app and am trying to get some info out of the API other than 400 Bad request. If I had these id's I might be able to get further

Comment: I put https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces into a browser (after I had logged into Asana) and it gave me all of my workspace ID's

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I put `app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces` into a browser (after I had logged into Asana) and it gave me all of my workspace ID's.

Comment: As of October 22 2014 cookie authentication for the API will no longer work, so you can't just put that url in your browser. You will need to use basic authentication with your API key or oauth. The simplest is to "curl -u "your-apikey:" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces . See http://developer.asana.com/api-change-to-cookie-auth/

Comment: works here as well. I wonder what's the ID we see on main pages... that should be the Organization ID, that should be the same as a Workspace?

Answer (score 3):

The Project ID is most easily found in the URL of your project when using the web interface: `https://app.asana.com/0/{PROJECT_ID}/...`.  It works with API calls such as pointing your browser to `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/tasks?assignee=me`