# Integrating PyCharm 4.5.3 with Asana

Tags: authentication, task, pycharm

Does anyone know how to integrate tasks from PyCharm CE 4.5.3 with Asana? There is an integration plugin (actually pre-configured generic REST API plugin) available.

I followed [documentation](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication) on generating the API key but PyCharm returns "unauthorized" error all the time.

API from within valid web browser session works OK:

- Project ID can be retrieved using GET on
  https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces
- Similar for issues:
  https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/tasks?assignee=me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Project ID is most easily found in the URL of your project when using the web interface: `https://app.asana.com/0/{PROJECT_ID}/list`.  This is the first URL which you should see if you simply go to `asana.com` and are already logged.  This number does not match what's found in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386609/get-asana-project-id), but it works with API calls such as pointing your browser to `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/tasks?assignee=me`

Using the URL in your first bullet will get the `workspace` ID which is not the same as the Project ID it seems.

Now, click on your user icon in the top right then:

1. My Profile Settings
2. Apps tab
3. API Key...

Copy your API key (or generate one first if you need) and then paste it into PyCharm as the Username for your Task Server.  Paste in the PROJECT_ID from above and leave the password blank.

Doing the above worked for me on OS X Pycharm 4.5.3

Comment: Bang-on! The way I was getting the project ID was plain wrong.

Comment: FYI Asana is deprecating the API Key in favor of Oauth.  Following the steps linked below and simply replacing the API Key with the resulting `access_token` worked for me: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#api-key-exchange